# Merging two JSON arrays with different key indices: Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have two JSON arrays say,

A:

```
[ {"id": 123, "name": "AnyName1", "type": "AnyType"},
{"id": 231, "name": "AnyName2", "type": "AnyType"} ]
```

B:

```
[ {"id": 569, "thing": "AnyThing3"},
{"id": 891, "thing": "AnyThing4"} ]
```

I want to merge these two arrays (irrespective of ids) in a common JSON array:

C=A+B:

```
[ {"id": 123, "name": "AnyName1", "type": "AnyType"},
{"id": 231, "name": "AnyName2", "type": "AnyType"},
{"id": 569, "thing": "AnyThing3"},
{"id": 891, "thing": "AnyThing4"} ]
```

**I want to achieve this without using a loop.** Can someone help me with any shortcut way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: actually, for an array  use [ ], can you fix your code? And im pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
let C = A.concat(B);
```

(There may be a duplicate, but it would take me longer to find it than to write the above.)